# Browser sending Empty Request to own Server

Tags: java, http, browser, server

I have been coding my own Webserver in Java recently because I thought it was neat having one and yesterday I stumbled upon a problem that I still havent fixed.
My browser (ungoogled Chromium) seems to send some empty requests or something like that to the Server.
I have implemented a Request Handler that is supposed to read the GET Request and extract the requested ressource.
It works like this : it takes the request for example : "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" and puts it in an Array with the String.split(" "); method the Array then looks like this : ["GET", "/index.html", "HTTP/1.1"]
Then I store the second value of the array, in this case "/index.html" in a variable that I can then use to locate the requested file and serve it to the User.
For debugging purposes I also print out the full requests sent by the user, that looks like this

GET, /index.html, HTTP/1.1
Host:, localhost:8080
Connection:, keep-alive
Cache-Control:, max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:, 1
DNT:, 1
User-Agent:, Mozilla/5.0, (X11;, Linux, x86_64), AppleWebKit/537.36, (KHTML,, like, Gecko), Chrome/86.0.4240.111, Safari/537.36
Accept:, text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site:, same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode:, navigate
Sec-Fetch-Dest:, document
Referer:, http://localhost:8080/index.html
Accept-Encoding:, gzip,, deflate,, br
Accept-Language:, en-US,en;q=0.9

However, sometimes the Request is just empty, It prints exactly this : []
It then throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException obviously.
This is pretty annoying because it works perfectly fine with the Linux "curl" command (curl localhost:8080/index.html)
I have already tried to solve the issue by using wireshark and looking for some weird stuff but none of my attempts to fix this issue have worked sadly.
I hope I could provide enough information for anyone to help me with my Issue, I've been trying to solve this for 2 days now and i'd be super grateful if someone helps me.
Thanks

Sorry for the poor text formation, this is my first stackoverflow question

Comment: What is the data read from the request? That gives more information than the result of the split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!request.trim().isEmpty())
{
   String[] requestArray= request.split(" ");
   if (requestArray.length > 1)
   {  
      //your logic as usual
   }
   else
   {
       log.error("The request has an incorrect format: "+request);
       //...
   }
}
/*else
{
   log.error("The request is empty");
   //...
}  uncomment this only if needed, as you could get spammed by empty requests */
```

Validate first the `request` String. If it's empty, avoid processing it, no need to split. Trim will remove leading/trailing spaces.

Validate then split() method's result, and place your logic in that block. If the condition is not true, avoid processing it.

Comment: the problem is that you may be hitting an array with no elements, as split() doesn't return anything, or may return just one element. The key is to avoid that, by validating first the request String

Comment: Your solution will make the browser spam more and more requests, first it says "incorrect format" for one time and after that it will just spam "empty request"

Comment: No, just one of them will be executed. If empty, "empty request". If not empyt but invalid format, "incorrect format". But both won't ever be shown, as the "incorrect format" log must pass the first filter. And if it does, that means the else block that holds the logic for empty requests won't ever be executed, as the request wasn't empty

Comment: They are 2 different errors, that won't ever be shown together; If "The request has an incorrect format" block is executed, the flow will continue without the execution of the last "else" block--> if you are showing an incorrect format, that means the request wasn't empty

Comment: I will just show you the stacktrace to see whats happening : 
incorrect format
Empty request
Empty request
Empty request
incorrect format
Empty request
incorrect format
Empty request
Empty request
Empty request
Empty request
Empty request
Empty request
Empty request
Empty request
Empty request
incorrect format
Empty request
Empty request
Empty
I try to access the server with my browser but it will just do this...

Comment: those are from different requests. If you print the requests, you'll see how Empty request holds a " " value, while the Incorrect format requests will not be empty, but don't pass the split filter. Never would a single request throw both Incorrect format + is empty errors

Comment: just updated the answer, check the loggers. It will print you which request exactly is throwing which error (no need to add the request to the isempty logger, as it will effectively be empty). There you can see how the request throwing the incorrect format error is not the same from the isempty error (because it's not empty)

Comment: I've copied your code now and what im seeing in the stacktrace is : "incorrect format" and then the request, which is actually totally normal, its "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" I dont know why its being flagged as incorrect format, when I put it into an Array it has the size of 2, so whats wrong??

Comment: GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 splitted to ( " ") will contain 3 values : 1-GET 2-/index.html 3-HTTP/1.1. So it won't pass the ==2 filter.

Comment: just change it to >1 and you will avoid that

Comment: as a suggestion, also avoid printing empty request errors, because as you tell, it will just spam the app. Just don't process it

Comment: I think I've found the issue, the requestArray is basically the whole header and not just the GET request, im gonna fix that and see if it works then because the length of the Array was always 28 and not 3, because it included all the response headers too

Comment: regardless of the number of elements, just test the code above and you'll see how no more ArrayIndexOutOfBounds is thrown by empty requests

Comment: The > 1 condition will just guarantee you get the index.html part . If the request holds more elements, then follow the logic you were using before

Comment: It has actually fixed it, I think, Thank you very much for your help man, You saved my Day!! (or my night, because its 3:50 for me xd) I cant even thank you enough! Ur awesome

Comment: same hour for me! hahah.. glad to help, good luck in life mate

Comment: @aran Can you elaborate for why browser sends empty requests? What is the reason?